# Web server not accessible from internet

Tags: networking, router, nat

I have ZTE ZXV10 W300 router and i have two computers connected to it , PC1 with static IP 192.168.1.24 and PC2 with dynamic IP , both running windows 7 integral with both firewalls set to OFF.

PC1 is running a web server (MiniWeb) listening on port 50080 with this command :

```
    miniweb.exe -p 50080
```

To access this web server from internet i configured the router (Public IP : 41.109.149.212) to do a NAT for port 50080 to be redirected to PC1 and after using the "Online Port Check Tool" every thing looks good and the sites is confirming the server is online (screenshot 1) :

[Screenshot of Online Port Check Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10W4a.jpg)

However when i try to connect to the web server from PC1(the same machine running the web server) or from PC2 using firefox i get nothing (screenshot 2) :

URL used : 41.109.149.212:50080

[Screenshot from Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nRYV.jpg)

After two days of troubleshooting i couldn't end up with a solution to access the web server from internet , help is very welcome.

Comment: This will only work if your router supports [NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning](http://www.nycnetworkers.com/real-world/nat-reflectionnat-loopbacknat-hairpinning/). Most consumer grade routers don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working for me, so I don't think you actually have a problem.

You may need to try it from a machine outside your internal network. If you're trying to access from the network that's serving the page then your router is basically having to loop the traffic back on itself at the gateway, and some routers won't do that.
Edit: this is what NAT Reflection/NAT Loopback/NAT Hairpinning is as referenced by David in the comment to your question.

Maybe disconnect your phone from the WiFi and try it there on 3G/4G - that's a simple way to get in from another network.

Comment: After some googling it seems that this is the main problem ( No support for Nat loopback for my ZTE router ) , is there any possible workarounds about this problem ?

Comment: How is it a problem for you? You can still access the web server internally on its internal IP and externally on its external IP.

Comment: I have to use another machine from outside the network to access it publicly , i want to workaround the missing NAT loopback feature if it's possible to access the webserver using the Public IP address from the same network if it's possible again

Comment: I'd get yourself a domain name (free DynDNS type or a proper one) and point that at the public IP. For your internal network you can just add the internal IP to the hosts list under that name and then you won't see the difference (even though there is one).

Comment: Working like a charm , thank you all guys for the help

Comment: As a way to complete the benefit for all persons , finally i could started the nat loopback which seem to be disactivated by default by logging to the ZTE router console using telnet and typing this command :  "ip nat loopback on" and it worked like majic again !!